# Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found. Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

i'm trying to use existing project as a library in android studio, it was easy in eclipse. i've imported the project into android studio and every thing works fine but when i try to use is as a library its says "Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found." 
i've included the the project in a directory named librairies and i'ave included in setting.gradle

```
include ':app'
include ':libraries:droidar1'
```

and i have changed the library into com.android.libray
and added the model in dependecy but its no use

Answer (score 1):

This error means it's looking for a module at a given path, in this case two paths **app** and **libraries/droidar1** and is not finding a buildable module at one or more of them. Make sure there is a **build.gradle** file at each of those paths with an `apply plugin` that will tell the build system what plugin to use to build the module.